# Método retornando Lista vazia

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Estou tendo um problema com um método em java. O intuito é dividir uma HashMap em paginas, e retornar uma ArrayList com cada pagina.

Código:

```
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Key>> getKeysMap(HashMap<String, Key> map, int maxItemsPerPage) {

    int pageItemAt = 0;
    int pageItemsTotal = 0;
    int mapTotal = map.size();

    HashMap<String, Key> page = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Key>> pages = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Map.Entry<String, Key> entries : map.entrySet()) {

        System.out.print("  DEBUG:: " + entries.getKey() + " " + entries.getValue() + " " + pageItemAt + " " + pageItemsTotal);

        page.put(entries.getKey(), entries.getValue());
        pageItemAt++;
        pageItemsTotal++;

        if(pageItemAt % maxItemsPerPage == 0 || pageItemsTotal == mapTotal) {

            pages.add(page);
            pageItemAt = 1;
            page.clear();

            System.out.println("-------------");

        }   
    }

    System.out.println(pages);
    for(int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(pages.get(i));
    }

    return pages;
}
```

Debug:

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seu problema esteja na inclusão do HashMap no ArrayList e posterior limpeza via método `clear`. Especificamente nesta seção:

```
if(pageItemAt % maxItemsPerPage == 0 || pageItemsTotal == mapTotal) {

    pages.add(page);
    pageItemAt = 1;
    page.clear(); // Limpa o HashMap

    System.out.println("-------------");

}
```

Este seção adiciona uma referência de seu HashMap na ArrayList e, logo após, apaga-o através do método `clear`.

Variáveis do tipo HashMap são referências para um valor e, ao executar a instrução `clear`, você apaga o HashMap referenciado pela variável `page`, **que é o mesmo valor que foi armazenado no ArrayList** `pages`.

Minha sugestão de correção para você é esta:

```
if(pageItemAt % maxItemsPerPage == 0 || pageItemsTotal == mapTotal) {

    pages.add(page);
    pageItemAt = 1;
    page = new HashMap<>(); // Novo HashMap para a variável page

    System.out.println("-------------");

}
```

Da maneira como está o seu exemplo, o resultado final da sua aplicação é um ArrayList com várias referências para um mesmo HashMap vazio.